# How to split lines with defined split number by user in pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Actually my question is on header. I want to split (or explode whatever you say) every line in my lineshape layer. For every line, I must define the split number and it should split them with equal length according to these numbers. Is it possible in pyqgis? I am working with QGIS 3.0.

Here is my layer:

[image]

After defining numbers it should be split like that (I wrote some of them split numbers and expected explosion:

[image]